# Returning null or what?

Tags: c#, null

I have a C# function like below, and in the `else` block, the function must return something. I don't know whether returning null is a good practice or not.

```
public Nullable<Point> GetSprite(int x, int y)
{
    if (x <= xCount && y <= yCount)
    {
        return new Point(x * spriteHeight, y * spriteWidth);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the `GetSprite` method **used**? And what is it **used for?**

Comment: Isn't `Point` a value type? You'd have to return a `Nullable<Point>` for a null return value to work..

Comment: Also the name is confusing, `GetSprite` doesn't return a "Sprite", but we'd need more context to recommend better alternatives.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I edited it. Yes it does not return a Sprite but it returns Sprite's coords.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you could just write:

```
public Point GetSprite(int x, int y)
{
    if (x <= xCount && y <= xCount)
    {
        return new Point(x * spriteHeight, y * spriteWidth);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And write in the documentation it could return null if `if (x <= xCount && y <= xCount)`

So who use your code could just write

```
Point point = GetSprite(x, y);
if (point == null) { /* something went wrong, check variables! */ }
else { /* ok! go ahead! */ }
```

I found this syntax very useful, and could not lead to bugs if the programmer is alerted about the null.

And, anyway you don't need the `else` block since the `return` call will stop the function (except if there are any finally blocks, but it's not the case.).

Comment: “could not lead to bugs if the programmer is alerted about the null” How do you make sure they are alerted? Because people don't always read documentation.

Comment: @svick You could throw an error if it's exceptional behavior. `if (...) { ... } else { thrown new InvalidArgumentException; }`

Answer (score 12):

It depends whether arguments that are out of range may occur in a regular way or if such method calls are considered being abusive.

- If such arguments are regular, then return `null` (that's perfectly okay).
- If such arguments are abusive, then throw an exception.

An exception should always catch an error and never be misused for a test.

If the purpose of the method is not only to return a sprite, but also to test whether a sprite is available for a set of parameters, then you could use the same pattern as with `Dictionary<T>.TryGetValue`:

```
public bool TryGetSprite(int x, int y, out Sprite sprite)
{
    ...
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Sprite sprite;
if (obj.TryGetSprite(x, y, out sprite)) {
    // Sprite available
} else {
    // No sprite available
}
```

When the return type is a non-nullable type, this is a good option. Magic numbers like `0`,  `-1` or `Int32.MinValue` are not obvious and are not always available (if the full range of values is required as a regular result). Even `null` might be a regular result under certain circumstances; for instance, a dictionary is allowed to contain `null` values. If you need this distinction between *contains null* and *not found*, the **TryGet...** approach is perfect.

The advantage over returning `null` is that you don't need additional knowledge apart from the method's signature in order to know how it works. Otherwise you are not sure whether an exception will be thrown or whether `null` or even an empty `Sprite` will be returned without reading the documentation. The disadvantage of `TryGetSomething` is that is looks somewhat cumbersome. However, starting with C#7.0 / Visual Studio 2017, you can declare the variable inline: `obj.TryGetSprite(x, y, out var sprite)` or `obj.TryGetSprite(x, y, out Sprite sprite)`.

Comment: I'd say that values like `MinValue` or `-1` are very rarely obvious.

Comment: Yes they should be avoided, but even Microsoft does it with `System.String.IndexOf()`. If used, at least a constant should be declared for magical numbers: `public const int NotFound = -1;`

Answer (score 12):

**Null is bad**. It's a flaw in the type system, and its inventor [deeply regrets unleashing it upon the world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149102/1272233). It adds an additional value to all reference types that [you probably don't want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989264/best-explanation-for-languages-without-null/3990754#3990754).

If you don't want to throw an exception (because failing to return a Sprite is a common occurrence and will likely be handled immediately rather than several layers up), then the correct solution is to return [a type that represents a value of type T that may or may not be there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079170/what-is-the-point-of-the-class-optiont?lq=1). For value types, Nullable fills that need reasonably well, because it forces you to handle the case where the value is missing. For reference types [you'll have to roll your own](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/228125/116461) since C# doesn't provide any.

Comment: You probably don't want that additional value, unless you do. That's why C# has `Nullable` for structs and why F# has `option`.

Comment: @svick The difference is that `Nullable` and `Option` keep the "nothing" value out of the original type. A `Nullable int` is not an `int` and you can't blindly assign one to the other. `null` is not an integer and it would make no sense to be able to assign it to an integer variable. The same logic holds for every other type - `null` is not a `List`, or a `Point`, or anything at all.

Answer (score 6):

I've read alot about returning null is not the best practice in the world, but like anything I think it will depend on it's usage and how often it might be called.  So, in your case this might be ok.  However, I'd just like to chuck out another way of doing things using the Null Object pattern.

Using this you would not return null at all but rather return a Null/invalid object.  Your calling code dependant on it's usage will be checking an instance type and so you might not need to even worry about whether it's null and potentially remove all those `== null` checks.

```
public Point GetSprite(int x, int y)
{
    return x <= xCount && y <= xCount
        ? new Point(x * spriteHeight, y * spriteWidth);
        : Point.OffGrid();
}
```

Then in your Point class itself you might have something like

```
public class Point
{
    private static readonly Point _null = new Point(-9999,-9999);

    public static Point OffGrid
    {
        get
        {
            return _null;
        }
    }

    public bool IsOffGrid {
        get { return this.Equals(OffGrid); }
    }
}
```

This way you might never even need to check for null at times.  However if you did your statements might look something like this now

```
var point = GetSprite(x, y);

if(point.IsOffGrid()) // equivalent to point == null
{
   // how do we handle it when it's off grid?
}

// do stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

Returning `null` is fine. You can check for `null` and decide what to do in the calling function.

Multiple `return` statement in a function is not a good practise.

So you can modify your function like:

```
public Point GetSprite(int x, int y)
{
    Point pObj = null;
    if (x <= xCount && y <= xCount)
    {
        pObj = new Point(x * spriteHeight, y * spriteWidth);
    }

    return pObj ;
}
```

Comment: “*Multiple return statement in a function is not a good practise*” – is this some official C# style guideline? It is universally accepted that multiple returns are a bad idea in C, because of resource cleanup on exit. However, C# is garbage-collected, so there is no technical reason to avoid multiple returns. In fact, I find multiple returns more elegant than using variables, especially for such a short function!

Comment: I disagree with you @amon but I also agree.  yes it is a short function, but this is clear about what the code is doing,  it is returning a `Point` object.  if you have a `return null;` then you wonder is it returning a null integer, a null pointer, a null coordinate. I know you classify the function as a `Point` Function but this code is clear as to what it is doing, Returning a `Point` object.

Comment: @Malachi I think that `return null` is very clear, and when you're reading a short enough function, it's hard to forget its return type. On the other hand, `return pObj` is less clear (even if the variable name was improved), because you have to look though the whole function to find out what it really means. (And I think finding all `return`s is easier than finding all usages of a variable.)